# KeyPressFcn not working on specific occasions

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a `KeyPressFcn` that seems to work whenever I'm obtaining new data and plotting it. When I'm not obtaining new data, the `KeyPressFcn` seems to no longer work. But if I do press the corresponding key, once I get back into data range and begin taking data again, it closes the figure.

I'm really confused why this is happening. My data collection happens only if a certain condition is met, but changing the `KeyPressFcn` and `exitflag` is inside my while loop and should be happening every time a loop occurs, thus I don't see why it wouldn't immediately exit my figure. Here is the code,

```
disp('DICOM Slice Viewer');
disp('" ": exit on space key');
global kpressed;
kpressed = 0;

%init figure on screen
global Fig;
Fig=DICOM_SliceViewer_createFigure(1,DICOMparam);
set(Fig.fig,'KeyPressFcn','global kpressed; global Fig; kpressed = get(Fig.fig,''CurrentChar'');');

exitflag = 0;
while (exitflag == 0)
    Naviparam=Navi_acquire(Naviparam);
    Naviparam=Navi_calc_data(Naviparam);

    %calibration calculation !TO BE CHECKED!
    DICOMPos = DICOMparam.calib.navi2dicom*[Naviparam.data.Endo_RefOffsetPosVec;1];

    ixR=round(min(max(DICOMPos(1),1),DICOMparam.Sx));
    iyR=round(min(max(DICOMPos(2),1),DICOMparam.Sy));
    izR=round(min(max(DICOMPos(3),1),DICOMparam.Sz)); 

    if kpressed ~= 0
        switch kpressed
            case ' '
                exitflag = 1;
                disp('**** Exit DICOM Slice Viewer ****')
        end
        kpressed = 0;

    end

    if Naviparam.datastr(5:11)~='MISSING'
        %refresh plot with 3 standard cuts
        set(Fig.sub1im, 'cdata', reshape(DICOMparam.Vd(ixR,:,:),[DICOMparam.Sy DICOMparam.Sz]));
        set(Fig.sub2im, 'cdata', reshape(DICOMparam.Vd(:,iyR,:),[DICOMparam.Sx DICOMparam.Sz]));
        set(Fig.sub3im, 'cdata', reshape(DICOMparam.Vd(:,:,izR),[DICOMparam.Sx DICOMparam.Sy]));
        drawnow;
    end
end

close(Fig.fig);
clear global;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem!

All I did was move the "drawnow" out of the if statement. This allowed me to draw my new data if it was taken, but also allowed some internal parameters to be updated in the figure I believe.